# The zeros of $\frac{\sin(\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, roots

It is known that the function $f(z) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ is entire. What are it's zeros? I think that $\sqrt{z} = k \pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. Then:

For instance $ \sqrt{z} = \pi$ implies $e^{\frac{\log(|z|) + i\angle{z}}{2}} = \pi$ and therefore $\sqrt{|z|} e^{i\frac{\angle{z}}{2}} = \pi$ then $|z| = \pi^2$ and $\angle{z} = 4k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ therefore $z = \pi^2 e^{i 4k\pi}$

On the other side  $\sqrt{z} = -\pi$ implies $e^{\frac{\log(|z|) + i\angle{z}}{2}} = -\pi$ hence $\sqrt{|z|} e^{i\frac{\angle{z}}{2}} = -\pi$ therefore $|z| = \pi^2$ and $\angle{z} = (4k + 2)\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ hence $z = \pi^2 e^{i(4k+2)\pi}$

Therefore the zeros are $$z \in \{(k\pi)^2 e^{i4p\pi}| k,p \in \mathbb{Z}, k\neq 0\} \cup \{(k\pi)^2 e^{i(4p+2)\pi}| k,p \in \mathbb{Z}, k\neq 0\} = \{(k\pi)^2 e^{i2p\pi}| k,p \in \mathbb{Z}, k\neq 0\} = \{(k\pi)^2| k \in \mathbb{Z}^*\}$$ Is it correct?

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Notice that $e^{2\pi i p} = 1$ for all $p \in \Bbb Z$ so your expression is simplified.

Comment: @N.H I was afraid to say that but I was thinking about it :)

Comment: @JohnHughes I edited that! Thank you for the remark!